# Call a number good if for all primes $p$ that divide it, $p$ must be either $3$, $5$, or $7$. How many good numbers have exactly $20$ divisors?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

> Call a number good if for all primes $p$ that divide it, $p$ must be either $3$, $5$, or $7$. How many good numbers have exactly $20$ divisors?

So we have that $good = 3^a \cdot5^b \cdot 7^c$ and from the condition we would need to have also that $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1) = 20.$ So it seems that we would have to count the possible combinations for which $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1) = 20$? However is that directly the amount of "good" numbers we could have?

Comment: Yes, that is the computation you need to do.  But your notion of good is wrong...good means $3^a5^b7^c$.

Comment: Did you mean $3^a\color{red}\times5^b\color{red}\times7^c$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks! Edited.

Comment: "Is that directly the amount of "good" numbers we could have?" Which number? $20$ ? You'll need to count all positive solutions to $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=20$.